# Cant delete a specific row in sqlite - Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

this is the code i used to delete a specific row in a table but i doesnot delete the row.please help me.

```
public void deleteone(String deletename)
    {
     try{
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();



     String whereClause = "KEY_NAME"+"=?";

     String[]whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(deletename)};

     db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, whereClause , whereArgs);


     }catch(Exception e){

     }
```

Comment: Do not silently swallow the exception. It may give you a hint what has happened. Also make sure there is a matching row in the table. Did you try to fetch the row with the same where clause?

Comment: ya i checked it. row matching only. any other way to delete a row.

Comment: what is the result of db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, whereClause , whereArgs); check as int rowsaffected = db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, whereClause , whereArgs);

Comment: it shows affected rows as 0 only but it has value in table.

Comment: Just try  int rowsaffected = db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS,  "KEY_NAME='" + deletename+ "'", null);  and reply what is result?

Comment: affected row is 0 only.

Comment: what are your table columns name?

Comment: table name- conatactinformation column name- name

Comment: try int rowsAffected =  db.delete("conatactinformation", "name='" + deletename+ "'", null);

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that `"KEY_NAME"` is supposed to be a variable and not a string. Do you have a variable `"KEY_NAME"` somewhere else in your code? Please post your whole code and it will make it easier to diagnose.